# Как в С++ задавать диапазон символов?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Можно ли в С++ задавать диапазон символов и если да ток как? Подскажите пожалуйста.
Как пример, можно ли задать что-то вроде?
    if (ch == [0-9])

Comment: Могу показать как не надо этого делать.
http://www.govnokod.ru/212

Comment: @igumnov, а мне понравилось. Я бы так не смог. Из-за лени.

Comment: немного не в тему но раз уж пошел разговор о примерах того, "как не нужно делать", то почитайте на Лурке статью про индусский код, примеры там просто зубодробительные, по сравнению с которыми эта куча кейсов - детский лепет

Comment: Ну вообще, чтобы определить принадлежность значения переменной некоторому множеству, надо сделать `set` и далее искать в нем, например, с помощью метода `count`.

Comment: @DreamChild Я фанат плохого С++ кода, самый банальный источник это лабы у студентов младших курсов, сайт govnokod.ru иногда треды на gamedev.ru или когда здесь просят сделать какую-то школьную задачу и перед этим показывают что "уже сделано", еще можно самому его придумывать или поискать в собственном коде. На лурке его мало слишком. Еще на ioccc.org есть неплохая коллекция но там он искусственный.  

    #define private public

Comment: что касается лаб у студентов, то со времен студенческой скамьи их не видел, так что лишен этого счастья)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, в стандартном С++ так нельзя. Вашу проблему можно решить таким способом (если тип переменной `ch` - `char`)

```
if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'))
```

Comment: спасибо. Даже сразу и не подумал, а в Си приоритет && выше чем у знаков сравнения?

Comment: думаю, и не только в Си

Comment: В Делфи тоже, но PHP нет.

Comment: вот уж  примеры у вас. Первый - язык для любителей некрофилии, другой - вообще нечто, на котором можно хоть, пардон, ж**ой писать

Comment: В С и С++ приоритет && ниже, чем у операторов сравнения. Скобки я поставил, потому что не очень хорошо помню таблицу приоритетов.

Comment: Да, мировой запас скобок неограничен.

Comment: @avp, да, в отличии от запасов памяти отдельно взятого немолодого индивидуума.

Comment: @mikillskegg: +1, в цитатник! (у нас тут его нету, да?)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
if (isdigit(ch))     // цифры (0 .. 9)
...
if (isalpha(ch))     // буквы латинского алфавита (A .. Z) + (a .. z)
...
```

ссылки по теме: [isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit), [isalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha).